# CSS Table Formatting Problems

Tags: css, formatting, format

I'm having some trouble formatting a table! I want to make a table in which all the cells stay at an equal width and height. In other words, so they don't overflow.

I can make it so that the cells don't overflow in the x-axis, by using `table-layout:fixed`, but I'm having some trouble preventing the cells overflowing in the y-axis. I want this to be hidden as well, but for some reason the CSS isn't co-operating with me!

I won't go into detail, as this isn't related to the problem I'm having, but **I'm not looking for an absolute solution** such as having a `height:50px` style. I would like a general solution to prevent this overflow, please!

I've provided some sample CSS and HTML below.  Please let me know if you need any clarifications! http://jsfiddle.net/pdtua295/1/

#### CSS

```
table.pztable {
  border-collapse:separate;
  table-layout:fixed;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
td.pzcol {
  border:1px dotted #2F2F2F;
  padding: 0px 2px 5px 2px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
span.pztext {
  font-family:Tahoma; 
}
```

#### HTML

```
...

<table class="pztable">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="pzcol">
       <span class="pztext">Alice</span>
    </td>
    <td class="pzcol">
       <span class="pztext">Bob</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="pzcol">
       <span class="pztext">S<br>T<br>R<br>E<br>T<br>C<br>H</span>
    </td>
    <td class="pzcol">
       <span class="pztext">This won't stretch horizontally.</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
word-wrap: break-word;

this will break even word

```
[I edited your code][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/pdtua295/1/
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested, but in the CSS for the td your should add height: 50px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: ellipsis; that should do it.

Comment: I don't want an absolute solution like height:50px. I stated this in the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css with
give min width and max-width to table td like

```
`table.pztable{
border-collapse:separate;
table-layout:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0px;
}
td.pzcol{
border:1px dotted #2F2F2F;
padding: 0px 2px 5px 2px;
text-align:center;
min-width:150px;
max-width:150px;
}`
```